# Conditional strings on the statusline

Tags: statusline

Is it possible to print a conditional string on the statusline?  e.g. `GREEK` if iminsert=1 and `LATIN` otherwise?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From `:help 'statusline'`:

```
The result can contain %{} items that will be evaluated too.
```

So if you write an expression inside `%{}` and add it to your `'statusline'` option, it should be evaluated and the result displayed. Here, your expression would be:

```
&iminsert==1?'GREEK':'LATIN'
```

The syntax of this expression is described in `:help expr1`; if the test before the question mark succeeds (here `&iminsert == 1`), the evaluation of the expression is the value just after the question mark, otherwise if it fails, it's the value after the colon.

To add this expression to your `'statusline'` value, you could write in your `vimrc`:

```
set statusline+=%{&iminsert==1?'GREEK':'LATIN'}
```

Comment: Note that the contents of `statusline` will be evaluated on every screen update. That's *a lot*. This simple expression is not a problem, but more complicated ones might be (like, say, getting the `git` branch name, the date, or some other relatively expansive operation).